# MIDL Compiler for Windows 10 LTSB

Tags: windows, midl

I'm trying to use the **MIDL compiler** to generate a .tlb file and I've found out that's part of the SDK.
But the problem is, at work we use **Windows 10 LTSB** (Enterprise) and that's not supported by the SDK. 
Do I have an alternative to MIDL Compiler? Or is there a version for SDK to use for Windows 10 LTSB?

Thank you!

Comment: Hard to guess what "not supported" could mean.  The only thing special about LTSB is that it does not get updated as frequently.  The current LTSB build is 14393.  Find older versions of the SDK [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive).

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, Hans for the link! But I've installed a virtual machine to use the compiler.